# How to show 3d polygon from three-dimensional coordinates array with javascript

Tags: javascript, json, three.js, polygon, geojson

I have JSON data like this. I have to show a 3d polygon with js exactly like the example. Can't change anything in the data. Need to fix it functionally. Have more similar data.

```js
// 2 features data
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "id": "2",
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "type": "wall",
                "sf_tilt": 90.0,
                "sf_orient": -32.0
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            2683852.4747061506,
                            1252231.906523199,
                            432.63800066187565
                        ],
                        [
                            2683852.4747061506,
                            1252231.906523199,
                            439.65200066187566
                        ],
                        [
                            2683852.200003838,
                            1252232.076997624,
                            439.39600066187137
                        ],
                        [
                            2683852.200003838,
                            1252232.076997624,
                            435.1080006618714
                        ],
                        [
                            2683850.956000865,
                            1252232.8489994688,
                            435.10800066185215
                        ],
                        [
                            2683850.956000865,
                            1252232.8489994688,
                            433.2940106618521
                        ],
                        [
                            2683852.4747061506,
                            1252231.906523199,
                            432.63800066187565
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "5",
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "type": "wall",
                "sf_tilt": 90.0,
                "sf_orient": 146.0
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            2683853.20506449,
                            1252236.2645763762,
                            435.108
                        ],
                        [
                            2683854.3609999996,
                            1252235.484,
                            435.108
                        ],
                        [
                            2683854.3609999996,
                            1252235.4839999997,
                            439.3960000002033
                        ],
                        [
                            2683854.6319999998,
                            1252235.301,
                            439.6550000030672
                        ],
                        [
                            2683854.632,
                            1252235.3009999997,
                            433.7652148642271
                        ],
                        [
                            2683853.2050644904,
                            1252236.264576376,
                            433.74104702266015
                        ],
                        [
                            2683853.20506449,
                            1252236.2645763762,
                            435.108
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here I have tried with threejs but not getting satisfied result.

```
function createBufferGeometry(feature) {
   const coordinates = feature.geometry.coordinates[0];
   const coords = coordinates.map((coord) => [coord[0] - offsets.x, coord[1] - offsets.y, coord[2] - offsets.z]);

   const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
   const vertices = [];

   for (const coord of coords) {
      vertices.push(coord[0], coord[1], coord[2]);
   }

   const positionAttribute = new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(vertices, 3);
   geometry.setAttribute("position", positionAttribute);

   const indices = [];
   for (let i = 0; i < coords.length - 2; i++) {
      indices.push(0, i + 1, i + 2);
   }
   geometry.setIndex(indices);
   geometry.computeVertexNormals();

   return geometry;
}
    
for (let feature of data.features) { 
  const meshMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      color: collors[feature.properties.type],
      side: THREE.DoubleSide,
      opacity: 0.5,
      transparent: true,
  });
  const meshGeometry = createBufferGeometry(feature);
  const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(meshGeometry, meshMaterial);
  scene.add(mesh);
}
```

My result with threejs, here for id 5 L shape not clear, adding an extra triangle also this tringle blinking.
[image]

Result with python `from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection` here L shape clear with same data.
[image]

Anyone please can help me with how can I get a similar result?